# connect asterisk with mysql

Tags: mysql, asterisk

i'm new on Asterisk & i need your help
i want to use mysql in dialplan in order to get some records using CALLERID.
i tried but i keep getting wrong result
Here is my code

```
exten => XX,1,MYSQL(Connect connid localhost XX root XX)
exten => XX,n,GotoIf($["${connid}" = ""]?error,1)
exten => XX,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} SELECT `name` FROM `contacts` WHERE `numero`='${CALLERID(num)}')
exten => XX,n,NoOp(${name})
exten => XX,n,NoOp(${resultid})
exten => XX,n(done),MYSQL(Clear ${resultid})
exten => XX,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})
```

if anyone can give me any help or advice i'll be thankfull

Comment: Can you pls provide a detailed error message / description instead of saying that sg is wrong?

Comment: What is the wrong result you're getting - and what were you expecting to get? Remember, you are encouraged on Stack Overflow to [edit] your question to make it as clear and useful as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you should use func_odbc.conf . take a look here on how to connect your asterisk . http://omid-mohajerani.blogspot.my/2015/09/asterisk-database-connectivity-via-odbc.html